# Displaying currency symbols in form dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in a commerce application where users can add an item listing.

In this create#item form, I'd like the user to be able to select (from a dropdown menu) what currency their pricing is in.

I've created a Currency model, views and a controller so the admin can add currency types. (I want the admin to be able to limit currency types).

Here is the currency migration file:

```
class CreateCurrencies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :currencies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :symbol

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

(The "symbol" being a string that holds the [currency HTML code](http://character-code.com/currency-html-codes.php))

I connected Currency and Item with a belongs_to/has_many relationship in the db. I then implemented a dropdown menu in the create#item form where users can select the currency.

My question is, how can I display the currency symbol in the dropdown menu?

Here's what I tried.

```
<%= f.collection_select :currency, Currency.order(:name),:id, "#{:symbol}".html_safe %>
```

The problem is, this doesn't display the currency symbols as I would have hoped; it just displays the string that was entered (the currency HTML code).

For example, with the code as it is, if an Admin entered the currency HTML code for $ (&#36), the dropdown shows "&#36" isntead of the expected "$")

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is: use `raw` method to unescape the html code.

I've just reproduced your code on my machine and noted a strange behavior.

For some reason `raw` doesn't work with `collection_select` and I can't figure why. Consider using `select` helper and 'manually' iterate your collection. Here is two identical variants:

```
= form_for "test" do |f|
  %p collection_select variant
  = f.collection_select :currency, User.all, :id, raw(:symbol.to_s)
  %p select variant (works!)
  = f.select("currency", User.all.collect {|u| [ raw(u.symbol), u.id ] })
```

[image]

Comment: The display looks exactly as I hoped for but for some reason, the currency_id isn't saving to the params hash. Any idea why not? (I tried implemented <%= f.select( :currency, Currency.all.collect {|u| [ raw(u.symbol), u.id ] }) %> in the create apartment form.)

Comment: Post your params. 
It should be like:
`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", your_model=>{"currency"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Test"}`

Comment: Thanks `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...w==", "item"=>{"Name"=>"Test Item", "from_date(1i)"=>"2016", "from_date(2i)"=>"8", "currency"=>"2", "price"=>"7"..... "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Item"}`

Comment: I guess currency_id is `"currency"=>"2"`

Comment: Yes. The problem is, that the currency_id of 2 is not being saved to the created instance of the apartment model.

Comment: Here is the server log:
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("name", "from_date", … "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?....)  [["name", "Test Item"], ["from_date", "2016-08-11"], ["created_at", "2016-08-11 15:07:50.146172"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-11 15:07:50.146172"]]...

No currency_id!

Comment: Here is the controller method:

def create
    @item = current_user.items.new(item_params)
end 

def item_params
params.require(:item).permit(:name, :from_date,.... :price, :description, :currency_id)
end

Comment: I suggest you create a new question with detailed information

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTMLEntities gem](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities). I would recommend setting it up as a helper method which you can use in the view.

helper file

```
def currency_symbol(currency_code)
  HTMLEntities.new.decode(currency_code)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @margo! I changed my the dropdown to:     <%= f.collection_select :currency, Currency.order(:name), :currency, currency_symbol(:symbol) %> Where should I add in the helper code that you provided? I added your code snippet into the currencies_helper.rb helper file but then I got the following error: uninitialized constant CurrenciesHelper::HTMLEntities.

Comment: presumably you've installed the gem, then you will need to require it in the helper file e.g. require 'htmlentities'.

Comment: Yes. Did both of those.